# Counting number of occurrences in a column which is grouped by two different columns using R

Tags: r, count

Below is the original `data.frame`

```
ID   Date       Type
123  2011-Jan   A
123  2011-Jan   A
123  2011-Jan   A
123  2011-Jan   B
123  2011-Jan   B
123  2011-Jan   C
123  2011-Mar   X
123  2011-Mar   X
345  2011-Jan   A
345  2011-Jan   A
345  2011-Jan   X
345  2011-Jan   X
456  2011-Mar   Y
789  2011-Mar   z
```

The desired output has 5 new columns which will have the 1st maximum count of column type (`Type_1`), 2nd maximum count of column type (`Type_2`) respectively. Below is the desired output

```
ID   Date       Type_1  Type_2  Type_3  Type_4  Type_5
123  2011-Jan   A       B       C       NA      NA
123  2011-Mar   X       NA      NA      NA      NA
345  2011-Jan   A       NA      NA      NA      NA
345  2011-Jan   X       NA      NA      NA      NA
456  2011-Mar   Y       NA      NA      NA      NA
789  2011-Mar   z       NA      NA      NA      NA
```

In one case with respect to ID-345 and Date-2011-Jan. There are actually two types (A and X) which have similar counts. Hence two new observations will be created for the same.

Comment: Look into tapply, maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a solution with `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(x)[,{x<-table(Type)
  as.list(names(x[order(-x)])[1:5])},by=.(ID,Date)]

    ID     Date Type_1 Type_2 Type_3 Type_4 Type_5
1: 123 2011-Jan      A      B      C     NA     NA
2: 123 2011-Mar      X     NA     NA     NA     NA
3: 345 2011-Jan      A      X     NA     NA     NA
4: 456 2011-Mar      Y     NA     NA     NA     NA
5: 789 2011-Mar      z     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

The basic idea is that what you want is the names of the sorted `table` produced within each `ID`-`Date` pair. We use `[1:5]` to force any longer tables to be cut off and any shorter tables to be filled out with `NA`. Personally I have to deal with sorted tables often so I've written a function that produces a sorted table, in which case this could be done cleaner and with one line--perhaps an exercise for you to brandish your chops.

Could also do this with `dcast` like so:

```
dcast(x[,.N,by=.(ID,Date,Type)][order(ID,Date,-N),
                                I:=paste0("Type_",1:.N),
                                by=.(ID,Date)],
      ID+Date~I,value.var="Type")

    ID     Date Type_1 Type_2 Type_3
1: 123 2011-Jan      A      B      C
2: 123 2011-Mar      X     NA     NA
3: 345 2011-Jan      A      X     NA
4: 456 2011-Mar      Y     NA     NA
5: 789 2011-Mar      z     NA     NA
```

Comment: I feel a reversal badge in your future!